# Read from a state variable without sending a transaction

Tags: solidity, gas

https://solidity-by-example.org/state-variables/

the site says "you can read state variables, for free, without any transaction fee". But when I do a get - call in Remix, a transaction is created and a gas cost is incurred !

What is the reason for this? Shouldn't get calls work without transaction fees in Ethereum?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the gas cost if the function call were part of a transaction.

For example, if a user initiates a transaction against a smart contract that spends gas, and that contract calls this get function, then the cost would be added to the total cost of the transaction. But if the call is made directly from an external account (Metamask), then there is no transaction and no gas cost.